# Unable to discover Bluetooth Devices on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am coding an app to discover nearby Bluetooth devices. However, I am unable to pick up any devices near me. I have scoured the internet and debugged and found out that after calling the registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent) method, nothing happened. My BroadcastReceiver's onReceive is not being passed. I have already requested the required permissions in the manifest and on runtime aswell and even checked if the required permissions are granted (which they are) but to no avail. I am unsure why my BroadcastReceiver is not receiving.  Below is my code.

Broadcast Receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadCastReceiver3 Received.");

        if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)){
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra (BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            mBTDevices.add(device);
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
            mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(context, R.layout.device_adapter_view, mBTDevices);
            lvNewDevices.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);
        }
    }
```

OnClick Function:

```
    public void btnDiscover(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired devices.");

    if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){

        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Canceling discovery.");

    }

    checkBTPermissions();

    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    Log.d(TAG, "mBluetoothAdapter: started discovery.");


    IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    Log.d(TAG, "discoverDevicesIntent: IntentFilter established with value of: " +  discoverDevicesIntent);

    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver3: receiver registered with discoverDevicesIntent.");
}
```

Checking of Permissions:

```
  private void checkBTPermissions() {
    Log.d(TAG, "checkBTPermissions: checking BT Permissions.");

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        int permissionCheck = 0;
        permissionCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH");
        permissionCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN");
        permissionCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
        permissionCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");

        if (permissionCheck != 0) {

            Log.d(TAG, "permissionCheck: !=0 .");
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1000);
        }
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version < LOLLIPOP.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0) {

            int grantresultslength = grantResults.length;
            Log.v(TAG, "" + grantresultslength);

            for(int i=0; i<grantresultslength; i++){

                if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                    Log.v(TAG,"PERMISSION" + i + " GRANTED");


                }else{
                    Log.v(TAG,"PERMISSION" + i + " DENIED");
                }
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "PERMISSION DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, what kind of Bluetooth devices are you expecting to find around you?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan hi! i want to scan other android devices around me.

Comment: Are other devices around you visible? Please check using your phones system settings bluetooth page

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan yes they are. but one interesting thing to note is when i use the Bluetooth Firewall Trial app listed on the Google Play Store to search devices around me, it will state "Cannot start discovery.Pls try later". I think there might be some issues with my device

Comment: This is a very odd app, I wouldn't think too much of it. If your settings show devices around you there is definitely something wrong with your code

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan true. Ive read the code over and over and cant seem to find my error. That is why i posted here to see if anyone else can spot the error haha